# how can oracle SQL return 6 count(columns) from one

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to create a query, which counts different emission classes of cars, grouped by different country codes.

I can handle to do it with one `emission_class`, but fail to create it with all 7 of them. I'm not sure how to start a subquery for this, or should I try to `UNION` them?

thank you for your insight!

The code for a singel emission class count:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT country_code,
  COUNT(emission_class) EURO0
FROM
  DB.CUSTOMER_VEHICLE
WHERE emission_class = 'E0'
GROUP BY country_code;
```

Comment: No need for `distinct` if you are using `group by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUM` with `CASE`:

```
SELECT country_code
     , COUNT(emission_class) AS total
     , SUM(CASE WHEN emission_class = 'E0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EURO0
     , SUM(CASE WHEN emission_class = 'E?' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EURO?
     , ...
FROM DB.CUSTOMER_VEHICLE
GROUP BY country_code;
```

Comment: I completly forgot to use CASE statment! I guess thats one of the many down side of relearn SQL after university from websites. Thank you very much it seems  to work (I just need to check it to be sure), with a lovely speed I might add.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think @Nightmaresux was trying to suggest:

```
SELECT country_code,
       emission_class,
       COUNT(*) cnt
FROM   DB.CUSTOMER_VEHICLE
GROUP BY country_code, emission_class;
```

It's an alternative to @notulysses's answer, but is slightly more flexible since it will work for any emission_class. However, it won't put each count into a new column, so it depends on what you're wanting the output to look like as to which proposed solution you go with.